# Problem with wget and file extensions

Tags: command-line, wget

I'm using `wget` to download a website that is a problem archive, some problems are available in html and some others are in PDFs in the same domain. The problem is when I use the option `--adjust-extensions` or `--html-extension`, the pdf files are saved in html extension. And when I don't use it the html pages look damaged, no background, indention, etc.

Here is the command:

```
wget --recursive --page-requisites --adjust-extension --quiet --convert-links test.com
```

So is there a way to download them all with correct extension?